# PySDL2 display grayscale numpy array on window surface

Tags: pysdl2

I have a grayscale image converted into numpy array.
I am trying to render this image on the sdl2 window surface.

```
sdl2.ext.init()
self.window = sdl2.ext.Window("Hello World!", size=(W, H)) 
self.window.show()
self.events = sdl2.ext.get_events()
    for event in self.events:
        if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
            exit(0)
self.windowsurface = sdl2.SDL_GetWindowSurface(self.window.window)
self.windowArray = sdl2.ext.pixels2d(self.windowsurface.contents)
self.windowArray[:] = frame[:,:,1].swapaxes(0,1)
self.window.refresh()
```

Right now I see the image in blue form. I want to render it as grayscale image. I have also tried to explore the sdl2.ext.colorpalettes but no success.

How can I display the grayscale numpy array on the sdl2 window surface

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with this today, and from what I can tell the reason is a difference in `dtype`s, the surface is a `numpy.uint32` while an image loaded from a gray scale image is only `numpy.uint8`. so full white in uint8 is 0xff when stored as auin32 it becomes 0x000000ff which is blue.

My dummy approach for testing is some numpy bit shifting:

```
self.windowArray[:] = self.windowArray[:] + (self.windowArray[:] << 8) + (self.windowArray[:] << 16)
```

I'm sure there is a better approach but at least it identifies the problem